# Coding to connect to Oracle through TNS

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tns

In my work place, through Oracle UI, I can only use **TNS as the Connection Type**, because they cannot open the port for me to do the connection. it's Oracle 11g.

But, right now I **need to write code** to connect to Oracle and get the data. I have tried several coding languages and none of them works...

Here're what I have tried

**Try 1: Spark Scala**, Spark Python is similar, and I'm using Spark Notebook here

```
val jdbcUsername = "[my user name]"
val jdbcPassword = "[my pswd]"
val jdbcHostname = "[Oracle hostname]"
val jdbcPort = [default port number]
val jdbcDatabase ="DATABASE"
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:oracle://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort}/${jdbcDatabase}?user=${jdbcUsername}&password=${jdbcPassword}"
val connectionProperties = new java.util.Properties()

Class.forName("com.oracle.jdbc.Driver")

import java.sql.DriverManager
val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
connection.isClosed()
```

This method failed and it shows

> No suitable driver found

**Try 2: Oracle Tutorial**

Then I checked [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e12137/getconn.htm#TDPJD130), it doesn't work for me because it's using **Basic connection type not TNS**
I have also checked relative Java connection method, didn't work for me

**Try 3: R**

Finally, I changed to R, this is the tutorial: [R connect to Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/R/entry/r_to_oracle_database_connectivity)

The first method using `RODBC` failed, showing

> message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Here's the code:

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcConnect("[Oracle Host name]", uid="[my user id]", pwd="[my pswd]", rows_at_time = 500)
```

For the second method, I cannot use `RJDBC` either. 
For the third method, I tried all the [mirror urls in my location](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html), and still cannot install package `ROracle`.....

My question is, **is that possible to write the code and connect to Oracle tables, using TNS as connection type?** I'm good with Python, Java and R, ok with Spark Scala

Comment: Why is your first one loading `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for an Oracle connection? And what do you mean about not being able to open a port - TNS goes over the network to the same port a basic connection would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found R works for me while my company blocks too many things. And R is very fast. Here's the solution:

**Step 1:** [Download .jar for ojdbc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html), need to choose the one for your Oracle version, for me it's 11g. The path of this .jar file will be the `classPath`

**Step 2:** Install Java jdk if you don't have it, otherwise you cannot load `rJava` package. [Download Java JDK here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="[your .jar file path]\\ojdbc6.jar", " ")
con <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@[hostname]:[port number]:[database name]", "[user name]", "[user paswd]")
d <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from [table name] WHERE ROWNUM <= 3")
d$[a column name]
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") to load driver first. And oracle jdbc driver jar file should be in your $CLASSPATH

Comment: 1/ Wrong driver class. Since 9i, you should use \oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'. Although I agree things do work with antic driver class name.
2/ Also you don't need to use Class.forName anymore since JDBC4
3/ Finally he is missing the '@' in his connection string.(jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//myhost:1521/myservicename)
4/ TNS connection is a different connection string altogether

Comment: @Alain Pannetier
`viktor@ViksPro:~/jlib $ unzip -l ojdbc7.jar |grep OracleDriver
     2285  06-30-14 11:32   oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.class
      459  06-30-14 11:32   oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver$1.class
    16742  06-30-14 11:32   oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class
      950  06-30-14 11:32   oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriverExtension.class
viktor@ViksPro:~/jlib $`

Comment: @BblKTOP, come on! [This is what Oracle say](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/111070-readme-083278.html) "In Oracle JDBC release 9.0.1 customer use of the classes in that package was deprecated. A new package, oracle.jdbc, was introduced and customers were advised to begin using the
interfaces and classes defined in oracle.jdbc. In every release
since 9.0.1 we have encouraged customers to switch to oracle.jdbc
and stated that oracle.jdbc.driver would be desupported. The time
has come. Customer code that references oracle.jdbc.driver will
not compile..."

Comment: `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` is the only way works with Spark Scala in Spark cloud so far (I'm using community version cloud and have limitation for settings). Meanwhile with Spark Scala, the connection string (jdbcUrl) does not need '@'.   I think what BblKTOP said has some value